# Deleting rows based on the column values in a file using awk command

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing, awk

I have a huge file like below. I want to delete the rows if second column is having values 60,30 etc., all these values I will get from another file in comma separated file.

```
position_id risk_measure_id Scenario_id value_usd
1   60  0   300.8
2   30  0   400.6
3   45  90  300.7
4   60  0   200.9
5   30  9   400.8
6   60  10  4000.9
8   20  0   5000.9
```

I can use below `awk` command to achieve it but if I have multiple values to exclude is there any easy way.

```
$ awk '{ if ($2!=60 && $2!=25 && $2!=30) print $0}' test.txt
position_id risk_measure_id Scenario_id value_usd
3   45  90  300.7
8   20  0   5000.9
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "easy way" ? You want to simplify the command ?

Answer (score 4):

Put your values in another file:

`values`:

```
60
25
30
```

Then read them into an array in `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {arr[$0] = 1; next} !($2 in arr)'  values test.txt
```

`FNR == NR` holds true when reading the first file, so the first block is only executed while reading the values. Because of the `next`, the `!($2 in arr)` is only executed for the second file.

Comment: OP doesn't even need a file. They would specify `-v values="60 25 30"` and then split that into array inside `BEGIN` statement.

Comment: @Serg I didn't feel like looping on an array. :)

Comment: lol, ok, but you're still looping on an extra file :p Still a good answer though

Comment: @muru I have a similar problem. I need rows having value greater than `36` in consecutive 7 columns. see the [data](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25783230/)

Answer (score 1):

Your command can be simplified further - you don't need `if` statement and code block, because awk can print lines using matching condition that precedes code block. If you only want to print the line, the code-block can be skipped altogether:

```
$ awk '$2!=60 && $2!=25 && $2 != 30'  input.txt        
position_id risk_measure_id Scenario_id value_usd
3   45  90  300.7
8   20  0   5000.9
```

Alternative solution would be to use array:

```
awk -v values="60 30 25" 'BEGIN{split(values,array)};{ flag=0; for(val in array) if (array[val] == $2) flag=1; if (flag==0) print }'  input.txt
```

What happens there is we create a string with all values we want,separated by space. In the BEGIN statement we break it down into array. Main code block sets flag variable to 0 upon reading each line, then we loop through all values in array and check if field #2 matches anything in array. If it does, we set flag to 1. After the loop exits we see if the loop found anything and set the flag, and if it didn't - print the line.

Shorter version of this approach is to use `next` command to break from the loop if the excluded value is found. This way, `print` function is reached only if there's no excluded value found:

```
awk -v values="60 30 25" 'BEGIN{split(values,array)};{for(val in array) if (array[val] == $2) next; print}'  input.txt
```